# Download dataset Which is a Zip file Contaning lots of csv file in notebook for data analysis

Tags: python, zip

I am doing a data science project.

I am using [google notebook for my job](https://colab.research.google.com/)

My dataset is residing at here which I want to access directly at python Notebook.

I am using following line of code  to get out of it.

```
df = pd.read_csv('link')
```

But Command line is throwing an error like below

What should I do?

Comment: What do you expect when you are trying to open a zip file with multiple csv's inside?

Comment: I want to load whole dataset which is zip file  from the link  in notebook and unzip the zip file which was downloaded for performing data analysis@NihalSangeeth

Comment: What methods have you tried? Where are you having difficulty in?

Comment: @vinvinn, try the answer and see if you can get out of it.

Comment: @pygo Thank you for your effort.

Comment: Are you using python3?

Comment: @NihalSangeeth, to whom this Question ?

Comment: @vinvinn,  you can upvote( clinking on the ^ ) the answer if makes sense to you in your understanding to improve your efforts or accept an answer if solves your problem.

Comment: I did try but stack overflow not taking my upvote i dont know why @pygo

Answer (score 0):

Its difficult to answer exactly as there lack of data but here you go for this kind of request..

you have to import ZipFile & urlopen in order to get data from url and extract the data from Zip and the use the csv file for pandas processings.

```
from zipfile import ZipFile
from urllib.request import urlopen   
import pandas as pd
import os

URL = 'https://he-s3.s3.amazonaws.com/media/hackathon/hdfc-bank-ml-hiring-challenge/application-scorecard-for-customers/05d2b4ea-c-Dataset.zip'

# open and save the zip file onto computer
url = urlopen(URL)
output = open('05d2b4ea-c-Dataset.zip', 'wb')    # note the flag:  "wb"        
output.write(url.read())
output.close()

# read the zip file as a pandas dataframe
df = pd.read_csv('05d2b4ea-c-Dataset.zip')    zip files       

# if keeping on disk the zip file is not wanted, then:
os.remove(zipName)   # remove the copy of the zipfile on disk
```

Answer (score 0):

Use urllib module to download into memory the zip file which returns a file-like object that you can read(), pass it to ZipFile(standard package).

Since here there are multiple files like 
['test_data/AggregateData_Test.csv', 'test_data/TransactionData_Test.csv', 'train_data/AggregateData_Train.csv', 'train_data/Column_Descriptions.xlsx', 'train_data/sample_submission.csv', 'train_data/TransactionData_Train.csv']

Load it to a dict of dataframes with filename as the key. Altogether the code will be.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from zipfile import ZipFile
from io import BytesIO


zip_in_memory = urlopen("https://he-s3.s3.amazonaws.com/media/hackathon/hdfc-bank-ml-hiring-challenge/application-scorecard-for-customers/05d2b4ea-c-Dataset.zip").read()

z = ZipFile(BytesIO(zip_in_memory))
dict_of_dfs = {file.filename: pd.read_csv(z.open(file.filename))\
               for file in z.infolist()\
               if file.filename.endswith('.csv')}
```

Now you can access dataframes of each csv like `dict_of_dfs['test_data/AggregateData_Test.csv']`.

Ofcourse all of this is unnecessary if you will just download the zip from the link and pass it as a zipfile.